# Destruction of local static objects

Tags: c++, singleton

Consider a situation like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
    static struct S {
        int value;
        S(int a): value(a) {}~S() {
            std::cout << "End is nigh";
        }
    }
    s(42);
    return s.value;
}

int main() {
    return foo();
}
```

In implementations of compilers, I researched these results in code that sets `S::~S()` up with the call of `_atexit`, i.e. local static object would cease to exist at some point after the exit of `main()`.

What happens if a destructor of an object in global static/extern scope calls a function that has a function-local static scope which, by definition, gets constructed the first time execution enters this scope and the call from the destructor is that first time? This also might be a case with a destructor of object function-local static scope constructs another object in function-local static scope.

This might be a case with a codebase that relies on multiple instances of Scott Meyers's implementation of singletons, where the object instance is a function-local static variable. I'm not sure what guaranteed to happen if such singleton has to access standard streams on this stage of execution, is it determined when they cease to function after `atexit` handlers.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question to be more precise. I think you're asking what happens if a destructor of an object in global static/extern scope calls a function that has a function-local static scope which, by definition, gets constructed the first time execution enters this scope and the call from the destructor is that first time. Whether this is undefined behavior, or there's a declaration order dependency which could go either way. That's actually a very interesting language-lawyer question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can I copy your phrasing? Heh, english not my native and it's 4 am

Comment: Be my guest, you're welcome to it.

Comment: Under what circumstances would you expect an object lifetime to commence *after* `main()` has returned?    How many of those circumstances would there be alternative implementation or design choices in which at least part of that object's life cycle (e.g. its construction) occur before `main()` returns?   In any event, standard I/O streams (`cout`, etc) are guaranteed by the standard to be accessible in constructors and destructors of static objects.

Comment: @Peter a whole set of choices made by newbee developers who learned about design patters and were eager to use them. SIngleton is  the easiest of them and  was overused, n some cases incorrectly (global initialization fiasco was happening for sure). Proper deinitialization  is essential because some of those objects namipulate system-wide shared resources (Shared memory? d-bus?) on platform that doesn't clean up if process ends. Thats my personal reason to agree with statement that Singleton is anti-pattern.  standard streams were used to "debug" this order.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the standard that directly addresses this. It is Undefined Behavior to call into a function with an already destroyed static object. I suspect that a first call to a function with a static variable is either OK once (it would be destroyed immediately after finishing the current object destructor as due to the static object destruction rules) then UB, or possibly is always just UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with a known solution, which unfortunately is rather complex. The best approach I know is the [Phoenix Singleton](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Elacher/lectures/Output/loki6/index.html?$$$slide01.html$$$) from Modern C++ Design. In short, you *can* rely on the values of non-class singletons, and you *can* reuse the memory of `s` to recreate an `S` object in the same location.

An alternative approach is to replace some utility singletons by objects that are jointly owned by the remaining singletons, i.e. via a `shared_ptr`. This will then be deleted after the last singleton goes out of scope.